# Change 'select' selection inside change event handler with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, html-select

is there a way to change the selection of an HTML `<select>` inside its own change event handler?

I have this code, which works perfectly fine. When I select an item in the drop down and then click the button, the item is removed from the drop down, added to the other array and the selection of the `<select>` is reset to the `null` element, which shows as `-- Please select filter --` on the page.

```html
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilter">
    <option [ngValue]="null" [disabled]="true">-- Please select filter --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let flt of availableFilters; let idx = index" [ngValue]="flt">{{ flt.caption }}</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="addFilter()" [disabled]="!selectedFilter"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

```js
selectedFilter: AvailableFilter | null;

// [snip]

addFilter(): void {
    if (this.selectedFilter) {
        this.addFilterInternal(this.selectedFilter);
    }
}

private addFilterInternal(flt: AvailableFilter): void {
    // Add filter to active filters
    this.activeFilters.push(flt);

    // Remove filter from available filters
    let idx = this.availableFilters.indexOf(flt);
    this.availableFilters.splice(idx, 1);

    // Reset filter selection drop-down
    this.selectedFilter = null;
}

// [snap]
```

My users wanted this to be changed in a way that the action, the button triggers, should be executed on selection. So I added a `change` listener to the `<select>` that calls the exact same function of the component.

```html
<select class="form-select form-select-sm" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilter" (change)="addFilter()">
    <option [ngValue]="null" [disabled]="true">-- Please select filter --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let flt of availableFilters; let idx = index" [ngValue]="flt">{{ flt.caption }}</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="addFilter()" [disabled]="!selectedFilter"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
```

But this does not work as expected. The element is still removed from the drop down and added to the other array, but the `<select>` does not reset to the `null` element. My guess is that this does not work because I am inside the change listener scope.

So I tried to encapsulate the `this.selectedFilter = null` code inside a subscription on a `Subject`, so it is executed asynchronously when the function ends (of course the function calls `next()` and `complete()` on the Subject after it moved the item between arrays). But this did not help, the behavior the the drop down stays the same.

Comment: Hi! Are you using "ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush" ? Also, can you try wrapping "this.selectedFilter = null" in a setTimeout with 0 delay?

Comment: @MaxTuzenko wrapping the expression inside a setTimeout did the trick. Thank you.  Please post this as an answer so I can accept it. Can you explain why this works, but the subscription did not? I thought that a subscription would also be called in a new scope because it is triggered asynchronously.
And for reference: I am using the default Change Detection Startegy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MaxTuzenko suggested in the comments, I wrapped the `this.selectedFilter = null` call in a `setTimeout()` with a delay of 0. This did the trick and it works now as requested.

So the TypeScript code above changes to this, see the last two lines of `addFilterInternal()` function.

```js
selectedFilter: AvailableFilter | null;

// [snip]

addFilter(): void {
    if (this.selectedFilter) {
        this.addFilterInternal(this.selectedFilter);
    }
}

private addFilterInternal(flt: AvailableFilter): void {
    // Add filter to active filters
    this.activeFilters.push(flt);

    // Remove filter from available filters
    let idx = this.availableFilters.indexOf(flt);
    this.availableFilters.splice(idx, 1);

    // Reset filter selection drop-down
    const self = this;
    setTimeout(() => self.selectedFilter = null, 0);
}

// [snap]
```